# How to output only necessary information in jq request

Tags: kubernetes, jq, metrics

I'm writing this jq request to output info about cpu:

```
cat kubernetes.txt | jq 'fromjson.kubernetes.pod | .name, .cpu.usage.nanocores'
```

My output is:

```
"podname"
null
"podname1"
null
"podname2"
null
"podname3"
3345678
"podname3"
123456
```

How to output only strings with values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the `select` function for this:

```
cat kubernetes.txt | jq 'fromjson.kubernetes.pod | select(.cpu.usage.nanocores != null) | .name, .cpu.usage.nanocores'
```

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions